# Update MySQL tables with PHP checkboxes

Tags: php, mysql, html, checkbox

Here's my table:

```
id | name  | check
------------------
1  | Paul  | no
2  | Bob   | no
3  | Tom   | no
```

id is an INT, name and check TEXT.

Here's the script:

```
<?php
include("database.php");

$dbc= new dbClass();
$query = $dbc->dbRunSql("select * from names order by name");

while ($result = mysql_fetch_array($query)){ ?>
  <form method="POST" action="">
  <input type="checkbox" name="names[]" value="yes"/><?php echo $result['name'];
} ?>

<br>
<input name="submit" type="submit" />
</form> <?php

if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
  foreach ($_POST['names'] as $entry){
    $dbc= new dbClass();
    $query = $dbc->dbRunSql("update `names` set `check`='$entry';");
  }
}
?>
```

This script works but updates all the rows, not the ones I check.

I have 2 questions:

1) What should I change to make it work correctly? (updating the ones that I check)
2) The ones that I don't check, how to update them in the "check" column as "no"

I hope you could understand what I meant.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: As a side note, store 'check' as a binary figure: 0 for 'not checked' and 1 for 'checked'.  Saves you a little DB space.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should do a WHERE clause in your query. What you currently have updates every row because MySQL doesn't know what to update. This is a fix for that problem:

```
$query = $dbc->dbRunSql("update `names` set `check`='$entry' WHERE id='$id';");
```

`$id` needs to be defined by you correctly, with something like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>" value="yes"/>
```

and then in your foreach loop:

```
foreach ($_POST['names'] as $id => $entry){
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! That did the trick. Just one edit for future readers, you missed a bracket in "names[<?php echo $result['id']; ?>". Thanks again!